# Attached form button doesn't trigger form submit when clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button, onsubmit, semantic-ui-react

Consider following example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Form } from 'semantic-ui-react'

class FormExample extends Component {
  state = {}

  handleChange = (e, { name, value }) => this.setState({ [name]: value })

  handleSubmit = () => this.setState({ email: '', name: '' })

  render() {
    const { name, email } = this.state

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Input placeholder='Name' name='name' value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <Form.Input placeholder='Email' name='email' value={email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          <Form.Button attached='bottom' content='Submit' />
        </Form.Group>
      </Form>
    )
  }
}
```

When `Form.Button` is attached clicking it does not leads to form submission.  When `attached` property is omitted `onSubmit` handler works as expected.

Is it expected behaviour or should I file a bug issue on GitHub?

Comment: attached is not a valid props for Form.Button. It is only for Button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Form.Button`](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form/#shorthand-subcomponent-id) don't have `attached` as `prop`.

By adding this `prop`, your `button` tag is getting converted to `div` tag. By adding `type="submit"` also don't work with this `prop` because after all it is `div` only. And to submit a form we need only `button` tag.

**Better to not use this `attached` `prop` in `Form`**.

You can only have this,

```
<Form.Button content='Submit' />
```

or you can use `Button` tag with `type="submit"`

```
import {Button} from 'semantic-ui-react'

<Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
```

Comment: OP asking for why the adding `prop` to `Form.Button` is not working as expected.

Comment: Removing `attached` property makes form submission work.  Setting `type` to `submit` with `attached={true}` still does not make submission work.  So I accept this answer.  Thank you @ravibagul91

Comment: By the way, `Form.Button` doesn't have `type` property too, but `Button` **do** have both. See my comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57353287/attached-form-button-doesnt-trigger-form-submit-when-clicked/57443924#comment101284917_57353659

Answer (score 5):

please add type="submit" to your submit button

```
<Form.Group>
    <Form.Input placeholder='Name' name='name' value={name} onChange={this.handleChange} />
     <Form.Input placeholder='Email' name='email' value={email} onChange={this.handleChange} />
     <Button type='submit'>Submit</Button>
 </Form.Group>
```

Comment: Adding `type='submit'` still does not work when `attached={true}` is set.  Form submission works fine when attached not set or set as false, with and without `type` prop set.

Answer (score 1):

`Form.Button` does not have `attached` as a property.

You can only use `content = 'Submit'` and the `attached` property won't work.

So this is the right code:

```
<Form.Button content='Submit' />
```

Or if you want new property:

```
import { Form, Button } from 'semantic-ui-react'


<Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
```

So if you want to import `Button`, you can use it and do the `type="Submit"` property and then inside add `Submit` as the text and then end the `Button`.

In conclusion, you cannot have `attached` inside so you have to remove it for it to work.

Comment: Yep, `Form.Button` have only `as` and `control` properties, according to docs.  But it doesn't have `type` property too.  At the same time, `Button` do have both `type` and `attached` properties (https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button/).  Feels like inconsistency.

Answer (score -2):

Just try inside your form

```
<Button>Submit</Button>
```

as in html, button inside form triggers the form submit event by default.

Comment: What? Why? You would have to first import `Button`.

Comment: This is not HTML. this is ReactJS.